# Javascript Object key sort using moment.js

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, momentjs

I have the following object structure

```
{ "Apr-18" : { ... },
  "Jan-18" : { ... },
  "Feb-18" : { ... },
  ...
}
```

I am trying to sort the month (MMM-YY) keys so that it shows as follows

```
{ "Jan-18" : { ... },
  "Feb-18" : { ... },
  "Apr-18" : { ... },
  ...
}
```

My code for this is below. I am using moment.js to convert the date into its epoch for the sort comparison. I have roughly followed the solution shown here [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key) However it's not working.

The console.log returns the object as it was, no sorting has occurred. What am I missing?

```js
const object = { 
          "Apr-18" : { "a":"b" },
          "Jan-18" : { "c":"d" },
          "Feb-18" : { "e":"f" }
}

const sortObjectMonths = (obj) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort( (a, b) => 
     Date.parse(moment(a, "MMM-YY") - Date.parse(moment(b, "MMM-YY")))
));

let sorted = sortObjectMonths(object)
console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: `Object.entries` returns an array of tuples `[key, value]` your sort function is treating them as values. You'll need to sort by `a[1]` and `b[1]` for it to work. But even then you are relying on the ordering of Object keys which isn't ideal.

Comment: object properties have no defined order

Comment: That's not strictly true @Bravo. see: [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) (though as I noted in my comment, it's not the best option)

Comment: Your data structure doesn't look right.

Comment: yeah, sorry, it is defined, of course ... but you're right, not a good option

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve]

Comment: Ah my mistake, so in the example, the 'clientName' key can be ignored. so basically the object should be defined as `{"Apr-18":  {}, "Jan-18" : {}, "Feb-18" : {} }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries()` to get the object property keys and values, then use `Array.sort()` to sort them using moment. We can simply subtract the moment values to sort them.

The `Array.sort()` accepts two arguments, firstEl, secondEl, in this case that will be [key1, value1], [key2, value2]. We can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to write these as ([a,],[b,]), where a and b are the object *keys* (e.g. 'Apr-18').

Then we'll use `Object.fromEntries()` to get our sorted object.

```js
const object = { 
    "Apr-18" : { "a":"b" },
    "Jan-18" : { "c":"d" },
    "Feb-18" : { "e":"f" },
}

console.log('Original object:', object)

const sortedObject = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(object).sort(([a,],[b,]) => { 
         return moment(a, "MMM-YY") - moment(b, "MMM-YY");
    })
)
console.log('Sorted object:', sortedObject)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: You should explain your use of destructuring here for the OP. You could also address all of the small errors the OP was making. ie: not accessing the `clientname` object, the unnecessary `Date.parse()` calls etc.

Comment: Good points @pilchard. I'll add some more details to the answer.

Comment: Including the clientname key was an error on my part, i've updated the question above to reflect this. Thanks for this answer. May I ask, what exactly is happening with the `[a,],[b,]` part ? - Answered, cheers!

Comment: We're using destructuring to write the .sort() arguments as [a,], [b,]. One could also write these as [keya,valuea],[keyb, valueb] where keya would be 'Apr-18' etc. I hope that explains things a little!

Comment: Ah, yes, that's fixed. Thank you @mplungjan.

Answer (score 1):

Without moment

```js
const months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr"]

const object = { 
    "Apr-18" : { "a":"b" },
    "Jan-18" : { "c":"d" },
    "Feb-18" : { "e":"f" },
}


const sortedObject = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(object)
    .sort(([a,],[b,]) => months.indexOf(a.split("-")[0]) - months.indexOf(b.split("-")[0]))
)
console.log('Sorted object:', sortedObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost okay but in .sort() the element a and b both are arrays of key and value. Key is at index 0 and value at index 1. Date.parse() won't work and converting the value by using new Date() is suggested. So, your code should be -

```
const moment = require("moment");

const sort = {
  clientname: {
    "Feb-18": { test: "c" },
    "Jan-18": { test: "a" },
    "Apr-18": { test: "v" },
  },
};

const sortObjectMonths = (obj) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).sort(
      (a, b) => moment(new Date(a[0])) - moment(new Date(b[0]))
    )
  );
};

let sorted = sortObjectMonths(sort.clientname);
console.log(sorted);
```